# Is there an AD setting that prevents Admins from resetting passwords?

Tags: active-directory

I have two separate Windows 2008 AD domains, one for Dev/Test and another for Prod.

I have asp.net/c# code on a Win2008/IIS7 server that uses calls suPrincipal.SetPassword(password) using LogonUser impersonation with a domain admin account.

The problem is that the same code works on my production AD but I get Access Denied when calling it on my Dev/Test AD using domain accounts with identical permissions on both domains.

Is there an AD policy or setting at the domain level that could prevent the a domain admin from calling the SetPassword function problematically?

Comment: Check UAC settings in each environment.

Comment: Is the principal you want to change a domain user or a local one? I'd first check if that domain admin, when logging in interactively, can change the password of that principal. Both local security policy (on the domain controller) and domain policies can override who is allowed to change passwords of a domain user. And local security policy of your local server can override who is allowed to change password of a local user.

Comment: Impersonating domain admins and resetting passwords from asp.net both seem like a really bad thing to do security-wise.

Comment: In addition to @JamesRyan: This is to avoid LogonUser() API it's better to use dedicated user in your application pool that has been delegated the right to reset passwords in specific OU(s). To become AppPool identity just use WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero), then WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token). This is much safer technic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Unfortunately, using the app pool identity isn't an option for this implementation, but the creds I'm using the LogonUser as is a non-privileged account with delegated OU reset pwd permission not a domain admin.  I was just using domain admin as a last resort for testing.   I ended up getting it to work by explicitly creating my context inside the impersonation block using ldaps port 686 and the ssl ContextOption. I found an obscure reference that SetPassword requires a secure connection.